# Problems with aggregate SQL functions in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot

I'm working on a website in a Spring Bootwhich is connected to a MySQL db. In the db i have two tables: `Player` and `Match` and i created a query that should return me a list of players with count of matches they already played. The problem is that typed aggregate function `count(M)` doesn't and I don't know that I'm doing wrong. In db I have e.g. `Player` with `id` = 1 and two played `Match`es, another with one `Match`, and another with 0. What I get as a result is one `Player` with 3 played `Match`es. If i type M.id instead of count(M), I get two rows for `Player` 1 (one for `Match` id), and onw row for the second. What is wrong with my code?

```
@Query( "select new dto.PlayerDTO(" +
        "   P.id, " +
        "   P.nickname, " +
        "   count(M), " +
        "from " +
        "   Player P left join Match M on P = M.player " +
        "where " +
        "   P.games like %?1% ")
List<PlayerDTO> findPlayersForGame(String game);
```

Comment: suggest you count(M.player)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `count()` on the joined table, you have to use `group by` statement:

```
@Query( "select new dto.PlayerDTO(" +
        "   P.id, " +
        "   P.nickname, " +
        "   count(M), " +
        "from " +
        "   Player P left join Match M on P = M.player " +
        "where " +
        "   P.games like %?1% " +
        "group by P.id ")
List<PlayerDTO> findPlayersForGame(String game);
```